# How to compare form input with database record?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to create a recommender system where the database has a set of predefined rules for a particular element.

For example,

Rule 1: `1,0,-,1,-,-,1,0`

Rule 2: `0,-,0,1,-,-,0,-`

Where a '1' is a yes to a question, '0' is a no, and '-' doesn't matter to the rule being generated.

The form will ask some yes/no answer questions and the answers given will also be a 1 for yes or 0 for no.

I'm stuck on the logic of how to compare the two however, particular considering the '-' which means the answer is effectively irrelevant as the rule will be given as long as the 1s and 0s match.

I'm thinking preg_match is required? But any help you can give would be much appreciated!

Comment: do you want this in javascript.. php ? you got tags for each so im not quite sure how you want this answered.

Comment: My Apologies, got a bit tag happy. php would be ideal.

Comment: Are the fields consistent? answer1, answer2, answer3 etc. If so just explode on the commas.

Comment: is the data going to be in a array or a string?

Comment: String would be ideal I think

Comment: Just noticed what you meant, I'm sorry.
As it stands I have the form input being inserted into an answers table. So I need to compare the data inputted from the form in the 'results' table, against the rules in the 'rules' table. Same principle as above though of rules table contains '0', '1' and '-' where '-' is not required for a rule to be chosen.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't compare strings. I would compare actual data.

Split the string on the comma, then loop through each answer and do the appropriate comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the results in your "where" clause when you select the rules from the database. It's ugly, but it could look something like:

```
WHERE (COL1 = 1 OR COL1 = "-")  AND (COL2 = 0 OR COL2 ="-")
```

etc...

This should theoretically be quicker than pulling down all the rules and looping through them.